# Logical Predicates

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Say you have the following predicates and you're using variables: P(x) = "x is a cow", Q(x) = "x makes milk", and lastly R(x,y) "x and y are the same object".

From there you have the following questions

(a) There are no cows.
   (b) Not everything is a cow
   (c) There exists at least one cow
   (d) There exist at least two cows.
   (e) There is at most one cow.
   (f) There is exactly one cow.
   (g) There is milk producing cow.
   (h) Cows produce milk.

Here is what I have:
 (a) $\exists x:\neg P(x)$
 (b) $\forall x: \neg P(x)$
 (c) $ \exists x: P(x)$
 (d) $ \exists x \exists y: [P(x) \wedge Q(x) \wedge Q(x) \wedge P(x) \wedge x \ne y] $

e through h im unsure of and I want to know if I made any mistakes so far?

Answer (score 1):

1. "There are no cows" $\equiv$ "It is false that there are cows"  $\equiv \, \sim \exists x, P(x)$
2. "Not everything is a cow" $\equiv$ "It is false that everything is a cow" $\equiv \, \sim \forall x, P(x)$
3. "There exists at least one cow" $\equiv$ "There exists a cow" $\equiv \, \exists x, P(x)$
4. "There exists at least two cows" $\equiv$ "There exists a cow $x$ and a cow $y$ such that $x$ is not equal to $y$" $\equiv$ "There exists $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ is a cow, $y$ is a cow, and $x$ is not equal to $y$" $\equiv \, \exists x, \exists y, \, P(x) \wedge P(y) \wedge \sim R(x,y)$.
5. "There is at most one cow" $\equiv$ "Any two cows are the same" $\equiv$ "For all $x$ and $y$, if $x$ and $y$ are cows, then $x$ is equal to $y$" $\equiv \, \forall x, \forall y, \, (P(x) \wedge P(y)) \to R(x,y)$
6. "There is exactly one cow" $\equiv$ "There is a cow $x$ such that any cow $y$ is equal to $x$" $\equiv$ "There exists $x$ such that $x$ is a cow and, for all $y$, if $y$ is a cow, then $x$ is equal to $y$" $\equiv \, \exists x, \, P(x) \wedge (\forall y, P(y) \to R(x,y))$
7. "There is a milk producing cow" $\equiv$ "There is $x$ such that $x$ is a cow and $x$ produces milk" $\equiv \ \exists x, P(x) \wedge Q(x)$
8. "Cows produce milk" $\equiv$ "Every cow produces milk" $\equiv$ "For all $x$, if $x$ is a cow, then $x$ produces milk" $\equiv \, \forall x, P(x) \to Q(x)$

Comment: Is there any good method for turning these into easier to decypher logical statements so that making the predicates and quantifiers in mathematical notation is simplier? Basically whats the easiest way to interpret these sentences?

Comment: I just think of alternate forms of saying the same thing and seek one that fits the mathematical notation.

Comment: With practice, it will become more easy. One memorizes what to do in each situation. For example, the expression "exists a cow such that ..." is always "exists $x$ such that $x$ is a cow and ...".

Comment: how did you translate number 5?

Comment: What is your doubt about number 5? Do you agree that the sentences "There is at most one cow" and "Any two cows are the same" have the same meaning?

Comment: I thought if its at most one then its only one max? i guess im wrong :(

Comment: To say that the number of elements of a given set is at most one is to say that this quantity cannot be greater than one. That is, there cannot be two distinct elements in that set. To put in another way, if $x$ and $y$ are elements of the given set, then $x = y$.